# Especificar versión del JDK en el MANIFEST-MF de un JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse, compilar

Cuando exporto mi proyecto de Java a JAR en **Eclipse**, solo me genera el MANIFEST.MF con la versión del MANIFEST.MF

`Manifest-Version: 1.0`.

Cuando lo compilo a través del **CMD** con el comando `jar -cvfm ejemplo.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class`, me genera el MANIFEST.MF con estas lineas:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Created-By: 1.8.0_201-b09 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Cuando lo compilo con Netbeans me genera en automático el MANIFEST.MF con las siguientes lineas:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_201-b09 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: test.TEst
```

En todos los casos, mis clases java están en Java 6 pero modificando aún el PATH de las Variables de Entorno, configurando los IDEs e incluso Java mismo, me sigue apareciendo la leyenda

> Created-By: 1.8.0_201-b09 (Oracle Corporation)

¿Cómo puedo incrustar de alguna manera la versión del JDK que corresponden las clases? En este caso es 1.6, esto porque hay varias personas que tocan los JARs, entonces revisamos el MANIFEST.MF pero a la hora de ver la versión en la que fue compilada con el comando `javap -verbose NombreClase.class | findstr "major"`, no corresponde.

¡Gracias!

Comment: la propiedad que quieres [no es parte de la especificación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) pero no te preocupes que internamente los .class tienen el nivel al que fueron compilados

Answer (score 0):

asegúrate que en tus variables de entorno tengas configuradas las variables "`JAVA_HOME`" y "`Path`" con los valores correctos:

```
JAVA_HOME con el valor: "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45" (cambiar a la ruta correcta de tu versión de java)
```

`Path` agregar lo siguiente al valor de la variable: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`